# How can I get through telethon authentication problem?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have some python code interacting with Telegram through Telethon library. And I have this authentication code:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")
api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']
api_hash = str(api_hash)
phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
username = config['Telegram']['username']
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)

client.start()

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(get_posts_num(tg_urls))
```

So the problem is that after command `client.start()` telethon requests to input the phone number and after that the authentication code I received but I've not received any code yet. I tried to repeat this procedure with other phones but nothing works ... So maybe I've missed something in the code or it's just Telegram's server-side problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

# connecting and building the session
client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():

    client.send_code_request(phone)

    # signing in the client
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
```